# Publish a local flv file to Flash Media Server through appendBytes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-media-server

Since i'm creating a stress tester for an FMS load balancer, i'd need to publish as many stream as i can , to see if the system will hold the load.

There's any way to send a local flv file through the NetStream.publish method?
After a little research, i found only the appendBytes solution, but it seems is not working.

Anyone has an example for this? or maybe a solution on how to fake a webcam so to send some bit of data.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but you could call functions on the server and pass large byte arrays (files, strings, whatever) as parameters.

Of course, this does not really count as a stream, but will put load on your server.

```
netConnection.call("functionName", responder(may be null), largeData)
```